# How to use Excel for quering large data efficiently?

Tags: excel, powershell, scripting, large-data, bigdata

For many years, I've used Excel to manipulate data and present results in a neat form. However, recently, I started a new job and discovered some barracuda-sized spreadsheets which had multiple worksheets with many, many queries, vlookups, etc. The complexity and speed of this workbook are terrible and give me nightmares!

After hours of searching the Internet in hopes of finding ways to make my Excel work more efficient, I decided to post here. My question: is there any way of combining Excel with some scripting technology in order to make my work simpler? For instance, I've found out that PowerShell can interact with Excel as well as query databases. Is it possible to take advantage of that in such a way that Excel's application would be limited to minor data manipulation and displaying results in a nice table. I'd be happy even if all data manipulation is done outside of Excel and only the values are pasted to specific Excel cells so that vlookups are eliminated...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question. Depending on your Excel version and license, you may be able to use Power Query to combine data sources, clean up data, perform calculations outside of Excel and load the data into the Excel data model where it is available for pivot reports. With Power Query and Powerpivot you can work with "Big Data", but you also need "big hardware", i.e. fast processors, lots of memory and maybe 64 bit Excel.

Comment: I know that it's a broad answer; I'd like to see what options there are. Thanks for bringing up Power Query, I have never used it before. Will give it a try soon :).